# Get the suffix of a dynamically selected id within a hover method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery selector with a hover method attached to it:

```
$("a[id^='foo']").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("color", "#eeeeee");

  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).css("color", "#ffffff");
  }
);
```

However, I want to alter a td decoration underneath the links with the 'foo' prefixes on their id's, which have a 'bar' prefix. For clarification: foo1, foo2, foo3 and bar1, bar2, bar3. How can I figure out what id is currently in effect and use its corresponding suffix within the same hover method?

Technically in semi-pseudo code I want to achieve this result

```
$("a[id^='foo']").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("color", "#eeeeee");
        // var x = charAt($(this).id.length-1)
        // $("#bar"+x).css("color", "#eeeeee");
  }, 
  function () {
    // ...
  }
);
```

I tried variations with $this.id, but I get undefined values.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this.id`, not `$(this).id`. Technically `$(this).attr("id")` would also work, but is not a great idea because it is going through several levels of jQuery indirection to achieve the same result.

Explanation: `this` is a native DOM element, with all the usual properties and methods (e.g. `id`, `className`, and `addEventListener` to name a few). `$(this)` is the jQuery object created from that DOM element, which only has jQuery methods, not any of the original properties.